# Is it possible to keep 'Inspect' mode always on in Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When Dev Tools are open, each time I want to click to select a page element, I need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>`. Is there any way to keep this option always on? To help you better understand what I'm asking, some may be familiar with the old Opera's (v.12 and earlier) dev tools which worked the way I want to have. In there, a previously clicked element will remain highlighted, but the 'Inspect' option will always remain active, thus producing at any moment two highlighted elements: the one clicked previously and the one being hovered over. I'm attaching a screenshot for illustration, where you can see 'Top Questions' highlighted because it was previously clicked, and 'autolayout' also highlighted because my pointer is currently hovering over it:

[image]

Can anything similar be achieved in Chrome's Developer tools?

Comment: Chrome Dev Tools defaults to the last tab that was open I think. I don't think there's a way to make it always default to the Elements tab.

Comment: Using AutoHotkey or similar tool it should be possible to intercept clicks and send Ctrl-Shift-C + click.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, guys. @Barmar that wasn't quite my question.

Comment: @wOxxOm the biggest problem with that method is that previously clicked element will not remain highlighted while I hover over other elements. Plus, I couldn't really find any tool called AutoHotkey.

Comment: [AutoHotkey](https://www.google.com/#q=autohotkey) is a scriptable key-remapper for Windows, here's an example of [Ctrl-click element picker](https://puu.sh/saDQo/ad6e7186c3.txt). Different OS would need a different utility, naturally. And of course proper implementation can be added only by the Chromium developers, you may suggest the feature on https://crbug.com

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately, I'm not on Windows. In any case, I assume this is not possible at this moment.